# Choose Enter Rather than Pressing Ok button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have many fields in the page and the last field is a dropdown with list of values. When I select an item in a dropdown and press Enter, it doesn't do the "Ok". Instead I have to manually click on Ok to Submit. How can I do by pressing Enter on my Keyboard rather than Clicking on "Ok" button after selecting the value from dropdown list. I have set the SubmitBehavior to true.

Comment: Grace, I edited your question to include an ASP.NET tag, since you mentioned SubmitBehavior, which is specific to web forms. StackOverflow has a reputation for quick answers; in the future you might want to stick around for a few minutes after posting a question to see if the community needs additional feedback. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

Try the solution here: [ASP.NET 2.0 - Enter Key - Default Submit Button](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx).

Comment: You answer talks about Win forms, the OP is asking about Web forms. I won't vote, though.

Comment: Thanks, I misread that site, the concept is the same, I'll find a new link

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a web form:

I'm no ASP.NET guru, but the default behavior of an HTML form is to submit in this case.  Common causes for this are the HTML form fields not being contained within the form element, or the submit button having a nonstandard javascript function fire instead of submitting proper.

I realize that's not an answer, but I hope it might help.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery you can do something like this

```
$("#fieldName").keypress(function(event)  
    {  
        if (event.keyCode == 13)  
        {  
            return true;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            return false;  
        }  
    });
```

See more here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `Page.Form.DefaultButton = OkButton;` in your code-behind.

Comment: In VB, I did something like,
Page.Form.DefaultButton = "OkButton"
and it seems to work as expected.